# Excel data dump column formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, concatenation

I format a data dump from our software and am trying to streamline the process. The first column contains several groups of characters that are separated with _ between each group. I then take that column and use text to columns to separate them. The issue is, I really only need the first two groups separated out, the rest I would leave combined together. In turn I end up building a concatenate to compile all of the minor groupings, however they are not always consistent with the number of columns being grouped resulting in additional _, which i then have to go back and remove.

I have to build this thing everyday, so if i can figure out the proper formula to streamline and build a macro into that would be fabulous. I do it to separate Column H & I from A, then combine with _ between each cell J-M.

Screenshot of data example:

[image: Data Example]

Comment: I think that it would be great if you could clarify "In turn I end up building a concatenate to compile all of the minor groupings, however they are not always consistent with the number of columns being grouped resulting in additional _, which i then have to go back and remove" - I don't really understand this part.

Comment: I think that an approach would be to process this dump in, say, Notepad++ and use the regedit capability to find and replace only the first two instances of "_" in each line (with "^", for example). Then you could use this character for the text to column operation and you would always get three columns.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is where Excel really needs some database operators like `PART`.

Nonetheless, we can do it ourselves.

[image]

#### 1. `B`

This one's easy, of course.

`=LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2,1)-1)`

#### 2. `C`

This one isn't really.

`=MID(A2,FIND("_",A2,1)+1,FIND("_",A2,FIND("_",A2,1)+1)-FIND("_",A2,1)-1)`

If you take the time to parse that out you'll find that it gets the `MID` of a string whose designation includes a nested `FIND` to find a `_` within a string that started from a `FIND` of a `_`. Fun stuff.

#### 3. `D`

Once you have that, getting the rest can be trivially done a number of ways. This struck me as a quick one, that doesn't include any arbitrary values:

`=MID(A2,LEN(B2)+LEN(C2)+3,LEN(A2))`